# Unwanted line breaks added wrongly in outlook

Tags: email, outlook, velocity, line-breaks, papercut

I am sending emails through a java program using velocity template.

When I open my email in Papercut, the render is looking good but when I open the same email with Outlook, I have a lot of unwanted line breaks.

I have modified the CSS in many ways like adding a specific width for table tag etc, I can see my modifications applied in Papercut but nothing in Outlook in terms of width.

[PapercutRender1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVf48.png)

[OutlookRender1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwSXT.png)

Here the Html template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My text </title>
    <style>
        /* -------------------------------------
          GLOBAL RESETS
      ------------------------------------- */

        img {
            border: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            width: 100%;
        }
        table td {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
                      BODY & CONTAINER
      ------------------------------------- */

        .body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }
        /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */

        .container {
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */

            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: auto !important;
            width: 580px;
        }
        /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */

        .content {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
                HEADER, FOOTER, MAIN
      ------------------------------------- */

        .main {
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .wrapper {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .footer {
            clear: both;
            padding-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .footer td,
        .footer p,
        .footer span,
        .footer a {
            color: #999999;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
                      TYPOGRAPHY
      ------------------------------------- */

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4 {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.4;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        p,
        ul,
        ol {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0;
            Margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        p li,
        ul li,
        ol li {
            list-style-position: inside;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        a {
            color: #3498db;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
                        BUTTONS
         ------------------------------------- */

        .btn {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .btn > tbody > tr > td {
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .btn table {
            width: auto;
        }
        .btn table td {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .btn a {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: solid 1px #3498db;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: #3498db;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 12px 25px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        .btn-primary table td {
            background-color: #3498db;
        }
        .btn-primary a {
            background-color: #3498db;
            border-color: #3498db;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
          OTHER STYLES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL
      ------------------------------------- */

        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .align-right {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .align-left {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        .mt0 {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .mb0 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .preheader {
            color: transparent;
            display: none;
            height: 0;
            max-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            mso-hide: all;
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 0;
        }
        .powered-by a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        hr {
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
            Margin: 20px 0;
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
          RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE FRIENDLY STYLES
      ------------------------------------- */

        @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
            table[class=body] h1 {
                font-size: 28px !important;
                margin-bottom: 10px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] p,
            table[class=body] ul,
            table[class=body] ol,
            table[class=body] td,
            table[class=body] span,
            table[class=body] a {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .wrapper,
            table[class=body] .article {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .content {
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .container {
                padding: 0 !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .main {
                border-left-width: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0 !important;
                border-right-width: 0 !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .btn table {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .btn a {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            table[class=body] .img-responsive {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                width: auto !important;
            }
        }
        /* -------------------------------------
          PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE HEAD
      ------------------------------------- */

        @media all {
            .ExternalClass {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass,
            .ExternalClass p,
            .ExternalClass span,
            .ExternalClass font,
            .ExternalClass td,
            .ExternalClass div {
                line-height: 100%;
            }
            .apple-link a {
                color: inherit !important;
                font-family: inherit !important;
                font-size: inherit !important;
                font-weight: inherit !important;
                line-height: inherit !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }
            .btn-primary table td:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
            }
            .btn-primary a:hover {
                background-color: #34495e !important;
                border-color: #34495e !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="">
<table style="width:560px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
                <table style="width:560px;" class="main">
                    <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                            <table style="width:560px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <!--<img src="http://localhost:8080/wmm-admin/icons/spidex-wmm_original.png" style="width:65%" /> -->
                                        <br/>
                                        <br/>
                                            <p><b>Webb, however, is 100 times more powerful than astronomy's godfather of space telescopes and can peer much deeper into space.

Hubble studies the universe predominantly at ultraviolet and optical, or visible, wavelengths, which is the same type of light we detect with our eyes.

Webb, on the other hand, is set up to specifically look in the infrared, which is invisible to our eyes but allows it to identify the glow from the most distant objects in the universe.

It works in much the same way night vision goggles use thermal imaging technology to capture infrared light.

Because the universe is expanding, just about all of the galaxies that we see from Earth are moving away from us. This means that to us, their light appears to have a longer wavelength, or a redshift.

For very distant objects, this red shift is so large that they can only be observed in the infrared spectrum, which is where Webb comes in, while Hubble focuses on ultraviolet light.

For this reason, the two will work in tandem for a while so that scientists can analyse the data provided by both to help advance our knowledge of the cosmos and how humans first came to be.

Webb began development in 1996 and was originally envisaged to launch in 2007, but a major redesign in 2005 put this back and a series of further delays led to it eventually making it to orbit at the end of last year.

THE JAMES WEBB TELESCOPE
The James Webb telescope has been described as a 'time machine' that could help unravel the secrets of our universe.

The telescope will be used to look back to the first galaxies born in the early universe more than 13.5 billion years ago, and observe the sources of stars, exoplanets, and even the moons and planets of our solar system.
Webb, however, is 100 times more powerful than astronomy's godfather of space telescopes and can peer much deeper into space.

Hubble studies the universe predominantly at ultraviolet and optical, or visible, wavelengths, which is the same type of light we detect with our eyes.

Webb, on the other hand, is set up to specifically look in the infrared, which is invisible to our eyes but allows it to identify the glow from the most distant objects in the universe.

It works in much the same way night vision goggles use thermal imaging technology to capture infrared light.

Because the universe is expanding, just about all of the galaxies that we see from Earth are moving away from us. This means that to us, their light appears to have a longer wavelength, or a redshift.

For very distant objects, this red shift is so large that they can only be observed in the infrared spectrum, which is where Webb comes in, while Hubble focuses on ultraviolet light.

For this reason, the two will work in tandem for a while so that scientists can analyse the data provided by both to help advance our knowledge of the cosmos and how humans first came to be.

Webb began development in 1996 and was originally envisaged to launch in 2007, but a major redesign in 2005 put this back and a series of further delays led to it eventually making it to orbit at the end of last year.

THE JAMES WEBB TELESCOPE
The James Webb telescope has been described as a 'time machine' that could help unravel the secrets of our universe.

The telescope will be used to look back to the first galaxies born in the early universe more than 13.5 billion years ago, and observe the sources of stars, exoplanets, and even the moons and planets of our solar system.
End test:</b> <i>The identified trigger result is higher than the set value.</i>                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
                </table>
                <!-- START FOOTER -->
                <div class="footer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="content-block"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- END FOOTER -->
                <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

On the other hand, If I put this text instead, I have no unwanted line break neither in Papercut nor in Outlook:
[PapercutRender2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST2nd.png)

[Outlook2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vcWs.png)

Do you have any idea of how I can get a correct render in Outlook ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the origin of the problem. I removed the "width: auto !important;" line from the .container class settings:

Before

```
.container {
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */

            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: auto !important;
            width: 580px;
        }
```

And after correction:

```
.container {
            display: block;
            Margin: 0 auto !important;
            /* makes it centered */

            max-width: 580px;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 580px;           
           }
```

Then it worked.